# How to coerce external associated types to my local struct types?

Tags: generics, struct, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have the following struct:

```rust
pub struct Liquidator<'a, P> {
    // ...
    pending_liquidations: HashMap<Address, PendingTransaction<'a, P>>,
    // ...
}
```

Whereby `PendingTransaction` is a struct imported from [ethers-rs](https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs/blob/0.2.0/ethers-providers/src/pending_transaction.rs#L25-L31):

```rust
pub struct PendingTransaction<'a, P> {
    // ...
    provider: &'a Provider<P>,
    // ...
}
```

I'm instantiating my `Liquidator` struct and attempting to insert an element in `pending_transactions`:

```rust
pub async fn do_something(&mut self, borrower: &Address) {
    // ...
    let pending_tx = contract_call.send().await?;
    self.pending_liquidations.entry(*borrower).or_insert(pending_tx);
}
```

(Here's the [definition](https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs/blob/0.2.0/ethers-contract/src/call.rs#L129-L134) of the `send` method).

But the code doesn't compile:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> liquidator/src/liquidator.rs:115:70
    |
24  | impl<'a, P> Liquidator<'a, P>
    |             - this type parameter
...
115 |                 self.pending_liquidations.entry(*borrower).or_insert(pending_tx);
    |                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `P`, found associated type
    |
    = note: expected struct `ethers::prelude::PendingTransaction<'a, P>`
               found struct `ethers::prelude::PendingTransaction<'_, <M as ethers::prelude::Middleware>::Provider>
```

It looks like the types don't match. How can I "coerce" the inner types of the `PendingTransaction` object returned by `send` to be the same as the type of my local `Liquidator` struct?

**Update**: here's my entire [liquidator.rs](https://gist.github.com/paulrberg/f5ccb309200416b941237cba3eebe8a7) file.

Comment: It looks like the error is not in the lifetime (although it is probably wrong too) but in the type of the value, that is a generic type in `Liquidator` but a different associated type in the implementation. You probably intend to instantiate the generic using the same type for both, but the compiler will not accept if that is not explicit.

Comment: Re lifetimes - yes, I updated the question after realising that the issue about associated types. I also updated the link to the definition of `PendingTransaction`.

Comment: How is the generic parameter `M` declared? What is the type of `contract_call`? You are going to have to specify to the compiler that `contract_call` is of some type `impl ContractCall<M, D>`, where `M::Provider = P`.

Comment: @EvilTak here's my [entire source code](https://gist.github.com/paulrberg/f5ccb309200416b941237cba3eebe8a7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your complicated example can be simplified to this:

```rust
struct Container<T>(T);

fn put_into_container<T, I>(container: &mut Container<T>, mut iterator: I)
    where I: Iterator
{
    container.0 = iterator.next().unwrap();
}
```

Which throws:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:6:19
  |
3 | fn put_into_container<T, I>(container: &mut Container<T>, mut iterator: I)
  |                       - this type parameter
...
6 |     container.0 = iterator.next().unwrap();
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found associated type
  |
  = note: expected type parameter `T`
            found associated type `<I as Iterator>::Item`
```

Without telling the compiler the type of `I::Item` there's no way for it to know it's the same type as `T`. We have to explicitly tell it like so:

```rust
struct Container<T>(T);

fn put_into_container<T, I>(container: &mut Container<T>, mut iterator: I)
    where I: Iterator<Item = T> // now compiles!
{
    container.0 = iterator.next().unwrap();
}
```

Likewise, in your example, you're trying to shove a `M::Provider` into a `P` without guaranteeing to the compiler that they are actually the same type. You can do that by changing this:

```rust
impl<'a, M, P> Liquidator<'a, M, P>
where
    M: Middleware + 'a,
    P: JsonRpcClient + 'a,
{
    // etc
}
```

Into this:

```rust
impl<'a, M, P> Liquidator<'a, M, P>
where
    M: Middleware<Provider = P> + 'a,
    P: JsonRpcClient + 'a,
{
    // etc
}
```

Which should allow the code to compile.